# What functionality I will miss if I will remove ejb3 subsystem from standalone.xml?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I want to prevent usage of `ejb3` in my system, so I want to remove `ejb3` `subsystem` from `standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
…
</subsystem>
```

What additional functionality I will miss in addition to ejb3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont loose anything beyond ejb3.